# How do I make a Chowder-esque texture?

Tags: texturing

How would one go about texturing an object where the texture stays fixed relative to the screen even if the object is moving?

Additional reference (the 'unmoving plaid' trope):
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnmovingPlaid

Comment: Please contain all the information in your question. It should be easy to describe it without the link. Links can expire.

Comment: Also: Gankutsuou overdose ( :

Comment: Please read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this?)

Comment: Well, I agree it would take two pictures in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture Coordinate node has an output called 'Window'. That means a texture is mapped according to the four corners of your rendered image.

[image: node setup for unmoving plaid]

Just create a texture that has the same aspect ration as your picture and you are done.

[image: da plaid]

Tvtropes puts it nicely: It's as if the clothing the character is wearing isn't so much patterned as it is a cloth-based wormhole to a similarly patterned universe (unmoving plaid).

And this is how it looks:

[image: ball]